# Shaml with NHibernate Contrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, shaml

Shaml looks awesome for project kick-start.

Would be great if it could be configured to also include NHibernate Search and other Contrib projects. Any plans for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the 1.x versions of NHibernate were very stable under mono, the recent version 2.0.1 and 2.1beta have many issues (like the lazy loading not working). I hope the 2.1 final will be much more stable under mono, and all the other projects (I'm mostly interested in NHibernate.Linq) will work without major problems too. Until that point I try to minimize the dependencies on external stuff and/or send patches to the maintnainers of the different projects (like DNOA). If you happen to succesfully integrate NHibernate 2.1 and/or NHibernate Search feel free to fork the github project.